# Nservicebus Saga

Tags: nservicebus

I am starting a nsb saga using IAmStartedByMessages. On the handle of this particualr message i am doing some kind of business logic if some cases fail i don't want the Saga to be persisted. How can i achieve this?

Thanks,
Ajai

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you call MarkAsComplete() in the handling method of the first message, then the saga won't be persisted.